# Given two ratios $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$, what is $\frac{p_1+p_2}{q_1+q_2}$ in their terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am ashamed to say that I cannot figure this one out: 
I am given two ratios $\dfrac{p_i}{q_i}$ where $i=1$, $2$. (We just know the ratios and not the numbers $p_i, q_i$. What I mean by this is simply that in the expression $\psi$ I cannot separate the $p_i$ and $q_i$)

I want an elementary expression $\psi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that

$$\dfrac{p_1+p_2}{q_1+q_2}=\psi \left(\dfrac{p_1}{q_1},\dfrac{p_1}{q_2}\right)$$

#### NOTE

- $p_i, q_i \in \mathbb Z$
- $q_2 \nmid q_1$, since otherwise we cannot find such a function.
- $p_2 \nmid p_1$ since this would make things trivial.
- Let us assume $(p_i,q_i)=1$.

Comment: Do you really mean to assume $q_1=1$?

Comment: Are you saying $q_1 = 1?$  Also have these been reduced to their lowest terms?

Comment: Oops Sorry! edited

Comment: You still have $\psi(\frac13,\frac12)=\frac25$ and $\psi(\frac13,\frac24)=\frac37$. Some further clarification is needed.

Comment: @Martin, I don't think clarification is needed, I think you've simply demonstrated that what OP wants is impossible. Never mind, OP has edited to rule out your example.

Comment: @Gerry In his last edit the OP defined a function $\psi \colon \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$. I doubt that there is some simple formula, but I am not sure how would I show, for example, that $\psi$ does not have continuous extension or $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.

Comment: Puzzled, what do you mean when you say you are given the ratios? If you aren't given $p$ and $q$, then how are you given the ratio? As a decimal? But those decimals are infinite --- how do you know when you have enough decimal places to determine a unique answer?

Comment: BTW this is called [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: If you do know the ratios, don't you know the numbers?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for that link. The ? function seems interesting. I feel less like an idiot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Martin Sleziak said in his comment, the function you defined is called the [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29).

As others have suggested, there is no reason to expect there to be a simpler formula than the definition you give. There is however a natural and obvious way to represent $(p_1 + p_2)/(q_1 +q _2)$ as a weighted average of $p_1/q_1$ and $p_2/q_2$, where the weights depend on $q_1,q_2$:

$$\frac{p_1+p_2}{q_1+q_2} = \frac{q_1}{q_1+q_2}\frac{p_1}{q_1} + \frac{q_2}{q_1+q_2}\frac{p_2}{q_2}.$$

This shows, for instance, that $(p_1+p_2)/(q_1+q_2)$ always lies between $p_1/q_1$ and $p_2/q_2$.

In fact a simple argument shows that the function $\psi:\mathbb{Q}^2\to\mathbb{Q}$ so defined is discontinuous (with respect to the usual order topology) everywhere except the diagonal. Indeed, consider replacing $p_2/q_2$ with a nearby rational but with much larger denominator. The value of $(p_1+p_2)/(q_1+q_2)$ is then changed to pretty much $p_2/q_2$. This puts a lower bound on the simplicity of a formula for $\psi$.

Comment: It's unlcear what your question is referencing, @Puzzled. $\mathbb Q$ has the usual order topology, and $\mathbb Q^2$ has the product topology. The point is, most "nice" formulas on $\mathbb R^2$ are continuous at most points under these topologies, but this function is at minimum discontinuous in a dense subset of $\mathbb R^2$. So that rules out "nice functions" on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for clearing that up.